# Web3 - 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance'

Tags: solidity

I am executing following code:

```
approve = async (addr, value) => {
      await this.state.token.methods.approve(addr, value).call();
    };
    
onSubmit={(event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      let etherAmount, tokenAmount;
      etherAmount = this.input.value.toString();
      etherAmount = window.web3.utils.toWei(etherAmount, 'ether');
      tokenAmount = window.web3.utils.toWei('20', 'ether');
      console.log(this.props.exchange_address);
      this.props.approve(
        this.props.exchange_address,
        window.web3.utils.toWei('20')
      );
      this.props.addLiquidity(tokenAmount, etherAmount);
}}
```

I am getting following error:

> Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with
> reason string 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance'
> at Token.transferFrom (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol:156)
> at Exchange.addLiquidity (src/contracts/Exchange.sol:30)

**Solution:**

```
approve = async (addr, value) => {
      await this.state.token.methods.approve(addr, value, {from: account}).call();
    };
```

Comment: You're likely trying to transfer more than you have as a balance. Do you have 20 of the token?

Comment: Hi, I found the solution. I need to approve the external contract to spend coins and very important I need to add {from: account} otherwise it will not work. I thought it is recognizing it automatically but I was wrong

Comment: Can you add the solution as an answer?